# unable to stick to custom domain redirected by application gateway with SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, tomcat, azure-application-gateway, custom-domain

Senario :
I have an azure app service where my application is running on tomcat and the ssl binding is done along with custom domain.

example:
custom domain is **something.com** and
app service url is **.azurewebsites.net**

I have an azure application gateway which is configure for WAF and it is use for redirection of my application in short url is : **ag.secure.azure.net**

Now the problem is
when I am try to hit the custom domain(points to application gateway) i.e., **something.com**
it dropping the SSl and redirecting me back to app service url which is block by the app services in **Access Restrictions section**

Note : I have create an Access Restrictions in the app service where only the application gateway is allowed.

I am stuck as what change should I make in my application or at tomcat level so that ssl redirection work fine.

Comment: How do you configure listeners and HTTP settings in the app gateway? Doubt that the app service URL is `appservice.azure.net` instead of `appservice.azurewebsites.net`?

Comment: yes that is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Adding the custom domain name , that is currently pointing to Application gateway(something.com), in the Web App will solve the issue.